# Rendering/markdown bug with bullet and code formatting

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, design, markdown

This answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/274813 originally contained formatting like:

```
- 
      LOG:  could not receive data from client:
```

which renders (as intended) in preview as:

[image: preview rendering]

but when posted it renders as:

-
LOG:  could not receive data from client:

It seems likely this is related to the [new rendering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting) or [new markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. This is indeed an issue around markdown rendering. We're using two different markdown renderers - *markdown-it* for the client-side preview and *Markdig* for server-side processing. Both are processing the formatting you've given differently.

It seems like the specific formatting you're giving is interpreted quite ambiguously among different markdown implementations ([here's a comparison](https://babelmark.github.io/?text=-+%0A++++++LOG%3A++could+not+receive+data+from+client%3A)).

This is something we'd need to fix in the upstream Markdown libraries we're using. For the time being, I suggest switching over to a slightly less ambiguous formatting - this seems to be rendered consistently across preview and server-side rendering:

````
- ```
  LOG: could not receive data from client:
  ```
````

This will show up properly in preview and rendered post:

- ```
  LOG: could not receive data from client:
  ```